# Input impedance into center tapped transformers

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, transformer, analog, filter

For a project, I need to find the input impedance into 2 types of transformers at their center frequencies (peak input impedance). Can anyone help me find the peak input impedance? Both L1s are coupled to each other and to L2 assuming ideal coupling coefficient (k = 1) [image]

Here's my work for the first one with some simplification but I have no idea if I did it right.

[image]

Comment: It's literally not homework, it's a for a project that I am trying to build and I am trying to analyze the transformer to compare against my simulations but my transfer function is too complex

Comment: If I am not wrong, the two impedance's are equal.

Comment: I can imagine they are, I'm just not sure how the peak impedance is found with the input not  in parallel with the RLC network.

Comment: They are. Did you ignore the coupling of the inductors ? What give your simulation ?

Comment: the simulation is fine and includes coupling but it's not helping me understand the analysis for the transfer function but I also don't understand how to incorporate the coupling. the text reference I am using doesn't have anything related to this type of tapped tank, it's all parallel RLC with loss maybe across a center tapped cap or inductor but nothing more

Comment: The proposed circuit has been used for a long time for the realization of the medium frequency stages AM or FM in the "old" way. A very long time ago ... So I started with a simulation in order to be able, next, to verify by calculation ... Someone which know and use EET would help ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD0wu.png

Comment: And here the equivalence you are searching ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mrCN.png ... C -> C*4 ; R -> R/4 for auto-transformer 1/1

Comment: Maybe it will help if you'd redraw the circuit as a Pi section: first shunt element is the first half of the transformer, then series R||C,  and the 2nd half of the transformer as terminating shunt.

Comment: Sorry. Auto-transformer is 2/1. Lapsus.

Comment: @Antonio51 Is there any place I can read about the analysis of these types of transformers?

Comment: Here are some notes.  I think the last is which can help you . Section 5->8. https://khitguntur.ac.in/shmat/NA%20Unit-III%20Coupled%20Circuits.pdf

https://www.philadelphia.edu.jo/academics/fobeidat/uploads/Electric%20Circuits%20II%20Course2/14%20Magnetically%20Coupled%20Circuits.pdf 
                ...    http://ds.agavaceae.ru/books/RDH/CHAPTR09.PDF

Comment: See also  my answer about https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575500/ringing-in-inductively-coupled-coils/575508#575508

Answer (score 1):

Here's half of your answer (the circuit below, Vi2):

$$Z_i(s)=\frac{L_1Rs}{R+s(L_2+4L_1)+s^2(4CL_1R)}$$

It gives right results in simulation.

Answer (score 1):

If coupling coefficients are equal 1 ...

First picture is same than second (swap input and ground at left).

Confirm answer of @Anark ...

[image]